# Python global variables between files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a functions.py file with all my functions. I want to print a variable from the main.py file which was created in a funtions in the function.py file. How can i do that?

functions.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

def open_tradeview():
    browser.get('https://www.tradingview.com/chart/')
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div"))).click() #Click on Hamburger menu
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[6]/div/span/div[1]/div/div/div[11]"))).click() #Click on sign in button
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[6]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/span"))).click() #Click on sign in with email button
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "username"))).send_keys("trading_view_bot@fastmail.com") #type in email
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password"))).send_keys("2C3-cc9r" + Keys.RETURN) #type in password
    time.sleep(18)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/article/button"))).click() #Click ad away
    time.sleep(26)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/article/button"))).click() #Click ad away
    time.sleep(5)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/button"))).click() #Click ad away
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "header-toolbar-symbol-search"))).click() #Currency pair
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".search-Hsmn_0WX.upperCase-Hsmn_0WX.input-3n5_2-hI"))).send_keys("VETUSD") #type in currency pair
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'VeChain / US Dollar (calculated by TradingView)')]"))).click() #select new currency pair
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div"))).click() #click on time frame
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[6]/div/span/div[1]/div/div/div/div[12]/div"))).click() #select 30min time frame
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[5]/div/div"))).click() #click on indicators
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[5]/div/div"))).click() #click on indicators
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/input"))).send_keys("ATR Trailing Stoploss") #search for ATR indicator
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]"))).click() #click on ATR indicator
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/span"))).click() #close search window

    
def get_atr_price():
    global atr
    global price
    atr = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div').text
    price = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/span[2]').text
```

main.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import yagmail
from functions import *
import functions
functions.get_atr_price()

open_tradeview()


get_atr_price()

print(atr)
```

when i want to print the variable atr i get an error that the variable atr is not defined

So basically how can I access every variable from both files?

Comment: Maybe write the variable to a file? (Just a quick work around.)

Comment: prefix the variable by the module to which it is global to.  i.e. print(functions.atr) for your particular print statement

Answer (score 2):

Have your tried with something like this?

```py
print(functions.atr)
```

Here is an example that works for me:

main.py:

```py
import functions

print("hello from main!")
print(functions.hello)
functions.funky() # this changes the value
print(functions.hello)
```

functions.py:

```py
hello = 4 # here the global variable is declared

def funky():
    print("hello from functions.funky()")
    global hello
    hello = 10 # changes the value
```

Output:

```
hello from main
4
hello from functions.funky()
10
```

EDIT:
If you want to work without global variables, you could make the `get_atr_price()` function return the atr and price, like this:

functions.py:

```py
def get_atr_price():
    atr = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div').text
    price = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/span[2]').text
    return atr, price
```

Then, in your main.py file, you can use them like this:

```py
atr, price = functions.get_atr_price();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and fast answer. I solved the problem using atr = functions.atr

Answer (score 0):

In your main function, you can take the result of any function in a variable then print

```
trade = open_tradeview()
atr = get_atr_price()

print(trade)
print(atr)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and fast answer. I solved the problem using atr = functions.atr

Answer (score 0):

Although global variables are needed sometimes, they should not be the normal way that data is passed among functions. In your case, why not just return the values you want from the function?

```
def get_atr_price():
    atr = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div').text
    price = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/span[2]').text
    return atr, price
```

and the usage is

```
atr, price = get_atr_price()
print(atr)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and fast answer. I solved the problem using atr = functions.atr

Answer (score 0):

Global doesn't work across files at least to my knowledge so I usually use the `return` command in python, you can return 1 thing 1 time per a def call, if you want to return more things at once you need to make a list/dict and then return that. You also need to define the variable the returned variable/list/dict will be associated with so for example

Variant 1 of functions.py:

```
def get_atr_price():
    atr = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div').text
    price = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/span[2]').text
    return atr, price
```

main.py:

```
import functions

x = functions.get_atr_price()
```

And x will now be a list where x[0] will be atr and x[1] will be price, or you can make it a little bit better by using dict:

Variant 2 of functions.py

```
def get_atr_price():
    atr = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div').text
    price = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/span[2]').text
    tmp = {}
    tmp['atr'] = atr
    tmp['price'] = price
    return tmp
```

now you can call onto atr or price almost directly with the same bit of code

main.py

```
import functions

x = functions.get_atr_price()
```

Now with the second variant, you can call x['art'] for art variable or x['price'] and it will be a bit more expandable and easier to navigate through.

Comment: Thank you for your help and fast answer. I solved the problem using atr = functions.atr

Answer (score 0):

Python controls the scope of variables per function and per module.

The `global` directive changes the scope of a variable used in a function as global. For instance, if all the code is in the same file, we can use the `global` directive.

```py
def func():
    global x
    x = 1

func()
print(x)
```

Which would print `1`.

Working with different modules, the variable name will be prefixed by the module name. For instance, if we have the `function.py` with the following content:

```py
def func():
    global x
    x = 1
```

The `main.py` needs to access x using the module name.

```py
import functions

functions.func()
print(functions.x)
```

Finally, using global variables may lead to maintenance problems. Hence, if it is possible, I would consider avoiding the use of global variables.

Comment: Thank you for your help and fast answer. I solved the problem using atr = functions.atr